# How to change what a zombie is holding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

## Problem

I am setting up a disguising system on Minecraft meant for a server that my friends and I are recording on. What I have right now is this:

```
tp @e[type=Zombie,name=Rocket] jackmaster110
```

The idea is that these stay in a repeating command block and the mob seems to be you. The problem is that the items you hold still appear and the mob doesn't hold it. I though, "No problem, I can just use some testfor commands." I set up commands to check which hotbar slot the player is on, and since the series is a roleplay, the hotbar will be preset. Anyway, after setting this up, I realized I had no idea how to make the mob switch items. I did some digging online and found nothing useful. The `testfor` command is here if you're wondering:

```
testfor jackmaster110 {SelectedItemSlot:0}
```

I am aware there is a plugin for this, but it isn't compatible with the replay mod which is what I'm using to record most of the shots.

## Background

The series is a Guardians of the Galaxy 1.5 roleplay and we need a Baby Groot (retextured baby zombie pigman), a Rocket (retextured baby zombie), and a Drax (retextured iron golem). That's why we need the disguising.

## Other Help

If this isn't possible, does anyone know a disguise plugin that will work with the mod, want to be our camera, or know of a different mod that can work with iDisguise. The last thing I wanted to ask is if anyone knows a way to stop the weird head movement the mob has.

Comment: @haykam thanks for the offer, and I would love to work something out if the disguising doesn't turn out okay, but I don't need it right now. If you want to be involved in a different way, you can contact me here: mcrulerwork@gmail.com

Comment: @haykam I know, the email is not personal. It's my official YouTube work email, so I can give it out when I need to make some sort of deal like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work:

`/replaceitem entity <selector> <slot> <item> [amount]`
**(entity is not a placeholder)**

In the above command:
`<selector>` must be a player name or entity selector.
`<slot>` is the inventory slot where the item must be placed (see below).
`<item>` is the item ID (e.g. minecraft:golden_sword).
`[amount]` is the how many of the items to stack (must be between 0 and 65, but is optional).

Slots for mobs include:

`slot.armor.chest`
`slot.armor.feet`
`slot.armor.head`
`slot.armor.legs`
`slot.weapon.mainhand`
`slot.weapon.offhand`

Remember, not all mobs will show or make use of the added item. A spider might have a sword, but what is it supposed to do with it?

Oh, and how are you supposed to know which zombie/Rocket you want to mess with? Selectors in Minecraft are a bother, but they work. You'll probably have to give it a custom attribute, such as a name. Give a Summoned mob a name like so:

`/summon Zombie x y z {CustomName:"Rocket",IsBaby:1b}`
**(I don't think you can use spaces for the selecting in the replaceitem command, so best just to use one word names for now. Even underscores can work.)**

Now, to give it a sapling!

`/replaceitem entity @e[name="Rocket"] slot.weapon.mainhand minecraft:sapling 4 1`

There are more things you can do with this command, but I think that this is all you need for what you want to accomplish. I got this information from the [Minecraft Gamepedia site for commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#replaceitem), and the more complicated stuff can also be found there.

Comment: why is your zombie a baby? Also, no need to use `:` in a selector. in fact it will make the selector fail. But other than that this is a great explanation that goes beyond what was asked.

Comment: @Plagiatus the zombie is a baby because Rocket is smaller than a normal human, about half the size, that's why the zombie has to be a baby.